# How can I submit a new version to the iOS app store without code changes?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want to change the screenshots of my iOS app. This requires me to create a new version of my app. I created a new version in iTunes Connect, but is there a way to tell it to use the same binary I submitted last time for this?

Alternatively, is there a way to take an archive from the Organizer in Xcode, just increment its version number, and pass it off as a new version?

Answer (score 0):

if you take archive from the Organizer in Xcode than it will give you last build which is uploaded in app store.
That build not contain new version number so you can't upload it.

**So its better to increase version number of your app and upload to app store.**